# Experiences with (cheap) third-party SFP modules?

Tags: cisco, sfp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are Arista SFP Transceivers Compatible with Cisco Switches?](https://serverfault.com/questions/242541/are-arista-sfp-transceivers-compatible-with-cisco-switches)

As the topic suggests, it would be interesting to hear what some of you with more experience have to say about this.

Pros
* supported
* known to reliable
* in use by all major companies

Cons
* not supported
* probability of low quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/242541/are-arista-sfp-transceivers-compatible-with-cisco-switches) question covers most of this.